# How to restrict control from initializing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple controls in my User controls like

text box, drowndown, listview , gridview and etc.

I have set some property in usercontrols which set enable and visible property of each control.

like isdropdownvisible, istextboxvisible and etc.

But **I want those control which are set visible=false does not get initialized**. so that processing.

Or suggest me another method which can enhance page speed

Comment: First, why do you think this affects page speed? If those are asp.net controls with `Runat=Server` then they wouldn't be rendered, so they don't impact the html response size.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, if e.g. they are databound controls, they could affect the server processing time, even if they do not affect the html response.

Comment: @SWeko: I know, but I wonder why OP is interested so much in them.

Answer (score 0):

Since part of the initialization itself is the setting of the visible flag, i.e. the system does not know whether a control is visible or not until after it is initialized, I'm afraid what you ask for is not only impossible, but illogical as well.

If you have a problem that some controls have too heavy initializations, that are not needed immediately, you can load them in some dynamic manner, but I could not be more specific, without some example code.

Comment: I am not saying that visible property of control should be used. instead I want to use the property defined in usercontrol. i think this makes you more clear

Comment: That is also unknown until after initialization. Please provide a relevant example.